# Accidentally skipped mokmanager while installing Nvidia drivers with Secure Boot in 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, secure-boot

I tried installing nvidia drivers through the GUI in Ubuntu 18.04 (Software & Updates tool). After asking for my password and taking some time (presumably for installation/configuration), it warned me about potential issues with Secure Boot asked me to set a code for use with mokmanager to prevent them. On the next restart, mokmanager popped up, but I accidentally told it to proceed with the boot and wasn't given the chance to enter the password I'd set earlier. I am wondering how to get this mokmanager prompt back and complete the installation/driver signing.

I have tried disabling and re-enabling the nvidia drivers through the GUI and also removing all packages matching '^nvidia-*' through the terminal and then re-enabling the nvidia drivers via the GUI, but I have never again been prompted to create a code for mokmanager and mokmanager has never showed up at boot. When I activate the nvidia drivers through the GUI, it shows them as active, but `nvidia-settings` gives a bunch of errors, beginning with `ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded`. It's difficult to understand what is actually going on.

Comment: A simple solution it to disable Secure Boot.

Comment: Secure Boot is required by my organization's security policy